# Python: JSON.dumps to structure { key: [ key: val ] }

Tags: python, json

I'm working a CSV file, and trying to write to JSON file from there with JSON.dumps. My desired data structure is

```
{
    "key1": {"innerkey1": "value1", … "innerkeyn": "valuen"},
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

however, JSON.dumps syntax seems to ask me to write

```
json.dumps({"key1": {"innerkey1": "value1", … "innerkeyn": "valuen"}})
```

which changes the meaning of the structure quite a bit (and isn't valid JSON because the dump is iterated over in a list comprehension.

I'm guessing I'm understanding dict syntax incorrectly, but can't quite pull this off.

EDIT: edited to change brace type. The issue remains that { "key1" … } is being written for each item, where I want one set of hogan braces to wrap around the entire structure, but

```
json.dumps("key1": {"innerkey1": "value1", … "innerkeyn": "valuen"})
```

throws a syntax error on the semicolon

EDIT2: json.dumps is called n-number of times, and each time is written to file. The output file looks like this:

```
{"key1": {"innerkey1": "value1", … "innerkeyn": "valuen"}},
{"key2": {"innerkey1": "value1", … "innerkeyn": "valuen"}}
```

this syntax makes JSON expect the comma at the end of the first enclosing set of hogans to signal end of file. The desired output is

```
{ 
    "key1": {"innerkey1": "value1", … "innerkeyn": "valuen"},
    "key2": {"innerkey1": "value1", … "innerkeyn": "valuen"}
}
```

Comment: your value for `key1` is something that looks like a `dict` but you're using `list` braces around it.

Comment: the desired data structure is invalid. `[]` should be `{}`

Comment: `{key: [key:val]}` should be `{key: {key:val}}`

Comment: How is your first `dumps` not giving you what you want?

Comment: It's operating over multiple rows, so I'm getting {"key1: {…}}, {"key2": {…}}, which makes JSON expect EOF at the first comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want `dumps` to only emit partial JSON for the inner keys, I don't think you can make it do that. I'd suggest either passing the entire dictionary (with all the top-level keys) to the `dumps` call so that it can write the whole thing, or taking care of the outer braces and keys manually and just using `dumps` for the inner dictionaries.

Alternatively, you can use `json.dumps` as you are, and strip off the starting and ending braces before writing them out (i.e. only print out `the_json[1:-1]`).

Comment: I'll go with that and the array slicing, it seems best.

Comment: Keep in mind you'll have to deal with the comma separators yourself.

Comment: That's fine. myfile.write(jsondumps + ",\n") should be fine

Answer (score 0):

By your edit, you want one `key1` to store many results?

```
{
    "key1": [{"innerkey1": "value1", … "innerkeyn": "valuen"},
             {"innerkey2": "value1", … "innerkeyn": "valuen"},
             {"innerkey3": "value1", … "innerkeyn": "valuen"}]
}
```

It's kind of a shot in the dark. And from the hip.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to output in each iteration some 'partial' json string (which by itself is not valid json), e.g.

```
"key1": {"innerkey1": "value1", … "innerkeyn": "valuen"},
```

But json.dumps doesn't output 'partial json', only valid json.

So, either:

- first collect all the results in a single dict for the whole document, and call json.dumps once.
- or, write out the first and final document brackets  and`"key1":` parts yourself, and use json.dumps only for the `{"innerkey1": "value1", … "innerkeyn": "valuen"}` part

Comment: Yes, agreed. Accepted tzaman's answer because he answered first.

Comment: No problem, it happens. At least you got confirmation from two parties ;)